# ZF2 - User Authentication Plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've implemented a plugin for user authentication control in a ZF2 application based on the Skeleton Application.

As multiple modules was not quite defined at the begining of ZF2, i've created in the folder Application\src 3 folders named Admin, Application and User which have their own Models, Controllers, Forms and namespace.

I've created my plugin class named `UserAuthentication` which extends from `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin` and I attached it with the `eventManager` in the Module.php file :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    var_dump('OnBootstrap');
    $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'loadConfiguration'), 2);
}

public function loadConfiguration(MvcEvent $e) {
    $application   = $e->getApplication();
    $sm            = $application->getServiceManager();
    $sharedManager = $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    var_dump('loadConfiguration');
    $sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController','dispatch',
            function($e) use ($sm) {
                var_dump('attach');
                return $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('userAuthentication')->preDispatch($e);
            }
    );
}
```

My problem is as follows :
This plugin works fine for controllers in the namespace `Admin\Controller`, but not for the Application's Controllers (namespace `Application\Controller`).
This break my head.

As you can see in the snippet, i've write multiple `var_dump()` to track the error, and for Application's Controllers this line seems not be executed :

```
$sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController','dispatch',
        function($e) use ($sm) {
            var_dump('attach');
            return $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('userAuthentication')->preDispatch($e);
        }
);
```

**EDIT**

I've found the solution. 

It was a problem of priority beetween events which their priority was 1 by default.
Just add an additional parameter on this function :

```
$sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController','dispatch',
        function($e) use ($sm) {
            var_dump('attach');
            return $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('userAuthentication')->preDispatch($e);
        }, 2  /**<--- Priority parameter **/
);
```

Comment: If you want to create more modules you don't create them in Application/src you need to make their own folder in modules with their own Module.php

Comment: This is not the problem cuz, I use differents namespace, then, I can't rewrite my application, consider it's one unique module with multiple namespaces.

Comment: BTW, you might want to look at the [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) user-registration and authentication module.